# 47 Ronin runtime?

Tags: alternate-version, 47-ronin

I was looking to buy 47 Ronin on Blu-ray, but there seems to be some confusion regarding the runtime of the film.

Amazon.com has it listed at a ridiculously long 238 minutes, this can't be correct. Every other site I've looked at, (Blu-ray.com, Wikipedia, Wal-Mart.com) has it listed at 118-119 minutes. IMDB.com, however, has it listed at 118 minutes, but they have an additional listing of a 128 minute "Extended Edition."

To my knowledge there was never an extended edition or director's cut of the film released in the States, and I can only find the 118 minute one available to buy. So, before I make the final purchase, is there an extended edition available in the United States?

Comment: I believe the '238 minute' version is really the [1941 movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_47_Ronin_%281941_film%29) (241 mins [on IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033654/combined)).

Comment: That could very well be the problem. What really threw me was the 128 minute "Extended Edition" that imdb.com has listed. I couldn't find that available anywhere, only the 118 minute version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the 4th paragraph down in ["The Movie Itself: Our Reviewer's Take"](http://bluray.highdefdigest.com/10562/47_ronin_3d.html) section; there is **rumored** to be a 3 hour version, but given the failure of the movie to break through at the box office it is unlikely that version will ever be released.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I couldn't get the link to work, but I guess it would stand to reason that if the rumored three hour edition will never be available, the 128 minute edition is probably never going to see the light of day either, at least not in the United States. It just struck me as odd that IMDB.com had two runtime listings. Thanks again.

Comment: They may have included the cut scenes in that 128 minute computation?  The blu-ray has 4 cut scenes as extras.

Comment: That's probably exactly what it is. I guess I'll just buy the 118 minute one, and watch the cut scenes in the extras. Again, I appreciate the input.